# UICollectionView within UITableviewCell. UICollectionView not showing once constraints are added

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, ios-autolayout

So I'm experiencing a strange bug. I have a `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableView` that shows whenever I don't add constraints. I'm trying to confine the collectionView to the left side of the cell using a simple constraint, but whenever I add the constraint the view disappears. I don't get any auto layout bugs/warnings, in fact the debugger doesn't throw any kind of flags. But still I can't get the collectionView to show when the constraint is added. There's supposed to be a label to the left of the collectionView. How do I get both to appear in the cell?

The code is as follows:

```
    // Init the average usage label
    self.labelMonthlyUsage = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    // Setup the average usage label
    self.labelMonthlyUsage.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.labelMonthlyUsage.text = @"Monthly Usage:";
    self.labelMonthlyUsage.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.labelMonthlyUsage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.labelMonthlyUsage.hidden = NO;
    self.labelMonthlyUsage.numberOfLines = 1;
    self.labelMonthlyUsage.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.labelMonthlyUsage.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    // Init the collection view
    EPSCVFlowLayout *layout = [[EPSCVFlowLayout alloc] init];
    self.cvMonthlyUsage = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 190, 150) collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.cvMonthlyUsage registerClass:[EPSCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
    self.cvMonthlyUsage.delegate = self;
    self.cvMonthlyUsage.dataSource = self;
    self.cvMonthlyUsage.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.cvMonthlyUsage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.cvMonthlyUsage.hidden = NO;
    self.cvMonthlyUsage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.cvMonthlyUsage.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.cvMonthlyUsage.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [self.cvMonthlyUsage setNeedsLayout];
    [self.cvMonthlyUsage layoutIfNeeded];

    // Add the views to the cell
    [self addSubview:self.labelMonthlyUsage];
    [self addSubview:self.cvMonthlyUsage];

    // Add constraints for the views in the cell
    NSLayoutConstraint *labelConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.labelMonthlyUsage
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                              toItem:self
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                          multiplier:1
                                                                            constant:0];

    NSDictionary *views = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[self.labelMonthlyUsage, self.cvMonthlyUsage]
                                                          forKeys:@[@"label", @"cv"]];

      NSArray *viewConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[label]-(>=8,<=300)-[cv]-10-|"
                                                                           options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:views];

    [self addConstraint:labelConstraint];
    [self addConstraint:viewConstraints];
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Try using Xcode's View Debugging feature.  It will show you where your views are located on the screen and why.  You can also tell it to show you clipped views, which often explains why they're not on the screen's visible area.

Comment: Did just what you said and found that, despite the constraints being set, the position, size and scrollable content constraints were all ambiguous. Now it all shows up properly once I added the correct constraints. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Phillip Mills for helping me figure out the issue. When I accessed the view debugger it showed the UICollectionView had ambiguous constraints for position and size. After adding some new constraints everything is working out fine. Thanks you for saving the day!